# Config jni in eclipse with mingw

Tags: c++, eclipse, java-native-interface, mingw

I have just started learning jni, I am tryning config mingw with eclipse but 
I have a trouble, I don't know why. I guest the root cause is config in eclipse because when I use VisualStudio everything is normal

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000000afb1048,pid=5716, tid=0x0000000000001a04
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_151-b12) (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.151-b12 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [cygwin1.dll+0x141048]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# D:\WorkSpace\01Java_HelloWorld\hs_err_pid5716.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

Comment: Did you check the mentioned report file?

Comment: Yes, I checked it, it is a log crash file, like this

0x000000000a1e7800 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5724, stack(0x000000000a6a0000,0x000000000a7a0000)]

Comment: Doesn't really give more information.
Looks like it is crashing withing your native code - I would recommend that you check what can fail there - maybe add some log messages so you can find the location in your code where your program crashes,

Comment: The native code side is only print() function, when I use visualstudio everything is OK but I cant use eclipse to build dll.

Comment: You could try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11728971/4181011

Comment: I tried that way, but no effective